splitGeometry does not produce two geometries with PyQGIS
I am working on a script that checks features for (rough) rectangularity and splits them if they are not.
If I correctly understand the splitGeometry method, it should produce two geometries if splitFeature = True. However in my script, it does not make two, but one. Why is that, and better yet, how can I correct it?
split_layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"Polygon?crs={layer.crs().authid()}", generate_layer_name("Split_Polygons"), "memory")
split_layer.startEditing()
split_layer.addAttribute(QgsField("id", QVariant.Int))

for feature in nonconform_layer.getFeatures():
    line_feature = line_layer.getFeature(feature.id())

    if line_feature is not None:
        line_geometry = line_feature.geometry()
        polygon_geometry = feature.geometry()

        if line_geometry.isGeosValid() and polygon_geometry.isGeosValid():
            result, new_geometries, topology_test_points = polygon_geometry.splitGeometry(line_geometry.asPolyline(), True)
            print("split geometries to be added to split layer: ", new_geometries)

            if result == 0:
                for new_geometry in new_geometries:
                    new_feature = QgsFeature()
                    new_feature.setGeometry(new_geometry)
                    new_feature.setAttributes([feature.id()])
                    split_layer.addFeature(new_feature)

split_layer.commitChanges()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(split_layer)


does your line intersect the polygon?

yes, I have specifically created a layer with polygons of several size and gestalt to make development and troubleshooting easy. They do intersect, they do get split, but the split parts do not get properly returned. I printed out the result of the .splitGeometry method as you can see in my original post, but it contains only one feature which is one correct half of the original polygon, just that the second half is missing

So your code runs but only returns half the polygon?

See this old but still valid bug report (not really a bug). The other part is your original polygon geometry (polygon_geometry object) which has been changed by the split operation. I believe this behaviour comes from the Geos implementation since the QGIS API uses the Geos library under the hood.

Thank you. That was the answer I was looking for. Code works now!
